# Second order differential equation for a spring system.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This question was in a past test and the lecturer explained differential equations very badly.

[image]

And I have no clue how to even start.
Please could someone provide a step-by-step solution for me and my classmates as no memo's were provided. It would really really be appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

1. [Hooke's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law)
2. Solve the differential equation using something like the method of [undetermined coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undetermined_coefficients)
3. For part (b) apply the boundary conditions.